# ChangeSet for Oracle plugin in Liquibase always empty

Tags: database, oracle, liquibase, changelog

I've downloaded Oracle Plugin for Liquibase, I've built it with maven and copied liquibase-oracle-3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar in /lib directory in Liquibase home. 
I've added namespace into changeLog file, as reported in documentation, and this is my changeLog file:

```
  <databaseChangeLog
 xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:ora="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

<changeSet author="myAuthor" id="xxx">
    <ora:encapsulateTableWithView tableName="TABLENAME"/>
</changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Update operation via CLI is always successful, but nothing happens on DB: the row in the DATABASECHANGELOG table referring this operation is correct but reports "empty" in description column.

I also added liquibase-oracle-3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar to classpath in liquibase.properties file, but it's useless.
Every changeSet traced in DATABASECHANGELOG table with specific Oracle plugin tag has the same checksum (7:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e) and reports "empty" in DESCRIPTION.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem: i launched by CLI command

```
java -jar liquibase.jar --changeLogFile=myChangeLog.xml update
```

but the changeSet resulted always empty: this because liquibase.jar didn't take classes from liquibase-oracle-3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar. I added liquibase.bat at environment variables in PATH and new command is

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=myChangeLog.xml update
```

and it works fine.